# What's the Point of Getting and Setting a Variable?

Tags: ios, swift

Currently taking a course on Swift.  Just wrote this piece of code:

```
private var _partyRock: PartyRock!


var partyRock: PartyRock {
    get{
        return _partyRock
    }set {
        _partyRock = newValue
    }
}
```

Why don't we just leave it as "private var _partyRock: PartyRock!"? Why the additional getting and setting?

Answer (score 2):

In the example you gave, there is *no* point. The example merely demonstrates the syntax.

But now think about the possibilities. You could do *other* things as the value passes between `partyRock` and `_partyRock` or *vice versa*. The code that sets or gets `partyRock` would never know that this is happening. It's powerful stuff.

And there are many other patterns that grow from this. For example, you can use it to create a *read-only variable* (by omitting the setter). Or, instead of setting/getting a private variable, you could be calling methods. The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 1):

As properties from other languages, the point is encapsulation. With properties, you can hide the details of validation or calculation.